# When resizing video.js using API, fullscreen does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video, video.js

My video is instantiated from markup, with a width and height (dummy values actually).

```
<video id='ytvidplayer' class='video-js vjs-default-skin' controls autoplay
preload='auto' width='xxx' height='xxx' poster='xxx'

data-setup='{}'>

<source src='xxx' type='video/mp4'>
<source src='xxx' type='video/webm'>


Whoops. Your browser does not Support HTML5 or Flash. Please upgrade your browser.
</video>
```

I am resizing my video once the page is rendered, to be one third (33%) of the screen size in width. This all works well.

```
var newHeight
var newWidth
newWidth = $(window).width() * 0.33;
newHeight = newWidth * 0.75;
$('#ytvidplayer').css('height',newHeight);
$('#ytvidplayer').css('width',newWidth);
//set related video div height eual to video height
$('#related_vids_scroller').css('height',newHeight);
var myVideo = videojs('ytvidplayer');
myVideo.width(newWidth).height(newHeight);
```

Everything works as expected, until I try to go fulslcreen. When the fullscreen button is pressed, the physcial "black" container of the video object goes fulslcreen, but the video stays at the API-resized width and height.

Is this a bug in video.js to not take the API-resized values into account (overriding) them on going fullscreen?

When I do not physically resize the video using the API, and have just the original markup (with a width and height)... fullscreen works fine.

1. I have tried using 'auto" for with and height in the markup, to try and have the video resize to its container ( a 33% div ), so I don;t have to resize it myself using the api. But on `w=auto` and `h=auto`, the video renders with no height, but seems to have the correct width... and it plays.. its just invisible (video progress bar is there tho, and at the correct width (fills the 33% div).
2. I have tried attaching to window.resize, but have difficulty in resizing the video using API there, is its a "toggle" really.. need to know if I am exiting or entering fullscreen mode... based on that, I need to resize up or down...

Any ideas? Am I over-complicating this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting css width and height on `#ytvidplayer` will be the problem. `#ytvidplayer` will either be a video element or a div depending on whether the player has been created at that point. Removing these and only resizing with the API only should work:

```
$('#ytvidplayer').css('height',newHeight);
$('#ytvidplayer').css('width',newWidth);
```

Comment: Hi misterben. Thanks for your input. While I posted this question, I went another route altogether... and rendered in an auto=h and auto=w, with some interesting styles to "pad" the video down.. I am not using the API to resize any more. For now, I cant confirm your answer, but will mark it as accepted. If someone comes along, and can confirm that this may not work, we will re-visit.